# adjective+for someone to do something

Tags: grammar, adjectives, infinitives

I know that we can normally use the combination "adjective+to do smt".

- He is close-minded to talk to.
- That topic is very hard to argue on.

How about adding "for" to those sentences?

- He is close-minded for me to talk to.
- That topic is very hard for my family to argue on.

Are they correct? Thank you.